# Can modify format of Calendar View tasks based on Status?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Can I create a Calendar View that will 'colorize' the entries based on Status field? I have a simple Calendar View on a Task list that I want to make more useful. DETAILED instructions appreciated, with sample code if you have it! THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that can be done in SP 2010. No code. Create a separate view for each status and filter each view to show only the events of the desired status. Also keep the default view that normally shows all items, but set the filter so it does not actually return any items.

Next, open the calendar with the default view. In the Calendar Tools > Calendar ribbon click the **Calendars Overlay** icon.

Select "New Calendar". In Calendar Name enter the Status or some descriptive text. In the Web URL field check that the current site is referenced and click the Resolve button. In the List dropdown select the current calendar and in the List View dropdown select the 
view for that status.

Tick the "Always show" box and hit OK.

[image]

Rinse and repeat for the other views.

The overlays will be added to the default view. If the default view is not filtered to show no items, then events will show up twice.

[image]